# Kendo UI treeList calling controller action multiple times on expanding node?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

> Following is the code/data which is returned as JSON to kendo Tree
>   List :

```
 var item = new IncomeStatementHierarchyItemModel()
                        {
                            id = GroupId,
                            parentid = Id.Value,
                            HasIndent = 0,
                            Title = drow[2].ToString(),
                            Actual = GetDataRowValueForPSA(dt, drow[2].ToString(), 3, 2),
                            Prior = GetDataRowValueForPSA(dt, drow[2].ToString(), 4, 2),
                            Budget = GetDataRowValueForPSA(dt, drow[2].ToString(), 5, 2),
                            Forecast = GetDataRowValueForPSA(dt, drow[2].ToString(), 6, 2),
                            PriorQuarter = GetDataRowValueForPSA(dt, drow[2].ToString(), 7, 2),
                            PSAClassification = psaClassification,
                            hasChildren = true
                        };
```

> Id and parentId is set to tree properly but after binding the data to
>   tree again controller action gets called for subsequent item.
>
> Transport function is used to create the datasource :

```
var drillDownDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: urlAction,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                cache: true,
                autoBind: true,
                data: function () {
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: of course !!!! it should not call multiple times.

Comment: Well, According to their documentation if you wish to implement Kendo tree Ajax style it will call each node depending on LoadOnDemand property, if this is set to true that method will be called only when you click on expand node , if LoadOnDeman=false, that method will be called for all nodes on document ready.

Comment: What I recommend to you is to use javascript version(because you will be able to use custom properties, in mvc you can't), so you will need to construct your list in controller, pass it to View via model and there you can convert it to Kendo TreeView data source, and this will load all in one time. If you need more help please post your full code including your tree model and I will provide full working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Parent Id does not mean too much for kendo tree here is what you need to do in order to get a kendo tree working in a good and right manner.

**1.You will need to have a model that looks like this:**

```
    public class KendoTreeViewItem 
    { 
        //required properties:
        //property names are lower case because I am planning to convert to   
     //javascript array and at that point kendo is looking for lower case   properties.
      public string id { get; set; }
      public bool expanded { get; set; }
      public bool @checked{get; set; }
      public IList<KendoTreeViewItem> Items{get;set;}
      public string text{ get; set; }
      public bool hasChildren{get;set;}
      public bool hasChildren{get;set;} 
       //Add other custom properties         
    }
```

**2.As I mentioned above, ParentId is not too important on kedno tree , but we will use it to construct from a flat list a real tree structure that will be used by kendo tree.**

In case if you already have this just skip this step.
**You can do it using something like that:**

```
 public static class KendoTreeHelpers
    {
        public static List<KendoTreeViewItem> ToKendoTree(this IList<KendoTreeViewItem> flatList)
        {
            Dictionary<long, KendoTreeViewItem> dic = flatList.ToDictionary(n => n.ItemId, n => n);
            var rootNodes = new List<KendoTreeViewItem>();
            foreach (var node in flatList)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ChildrenIds))
                {
                    node.Items = null;
                }
                if (node.ParentId.HasValue)
                {
                    var parent = dic[node.ParentId.Value];
                    node.ParentId = parent.ItemId;
                    parent.Items.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    rootNodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
            return rootNodes;
        }
    }
```

**3.So your method in  controller should look like this:**

```
 public ActionResult DisplayTree()
        {
            IList<KendoTreeViewItem> flatList = GetFlatList();//your method to get list.
            IList<KendoTreeViewItem> tree = flatList.ToKendoTree();
            return View(tree);
        }
```

**4.View**

```
@model IList<KendoTreeViewItem>

 <div id="treeview">

                        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
                dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                    data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            children: "Items"
                        }
                    }
                }),             

            });
        });
```

Using this you will obtain what you want, *note that behavior that you are describing is a normal behavior for ajax bin ding*.

Comment: BTW i am talking about tree-list and not treeview